# Cannot store UIImage in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutabledictionary

I'm obtaining an image from Parse server, but when I receive it and store it in an `NSMutableDictionary`, it fails to stay there when I check it.

```
NSString* messageSenderId = [receivedMessage objectForKey:@"Sender Id"];
NSLog(@"messageSenderId = %@", messageSenderId);

if([self.avatarDictionary objectForKey:messageSenderId] == nil) { // avatar image for sender not yet stored

PFQuery* userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:messageSenderId];
PFUser* messageSender = (PFUser *)[[messageSenderQuery findObjects] firstObject];

PFFile *avatarImage = messageSender[@"profilePictureSmall"];
[avatarImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        UIImage* storedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [self.avatarDictionary setObject:storedImage forKey:messageSender.objectId];
        NSLog(@"objectForKey: %@", [self.avatarDictionary objectForKey:messageSender.objectId]);
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

When I check for the `storedImage` variable I can see that it is not empty. But, the `NSLog` reveals that there is no object for that key after I store it inside.

Comment: Did you initialize your `self.avatarDictionary` please check that, you must to do `self.avatarDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure that you can, but I would not.
Your problem can be due to the fact that you didn't initialize the mutable dictionary.
Images take a lot of memory and if you are storing a lot of images your app can be killed by the system.
A better approach could be save images locally and store the path to them in the mutable dictionary.
Or if you still want to store images in RAM, you can use [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache). NSCache basically is a mutable dictionary, but it has a better memory management by evicting automatically resources and it is thread safe.

Comment: Yep. It wasn't initialised, thank you.

I didn't know that my app can be killed because of many images stored in NSDictionary. Do you know what the limit is?

Comment: Your app can be killed if the memory occupied exceed a limit. the limit depends on the device and is not written anywhere. Apple suggest to keep you memory profile low.